# Upload csv to Teradata DB using Python and Fastload utility

Tags: python, teradata

I have spent a reasonable amount of time researching about a plausible way of uploading a csv file using Teradata Fastload but documentation is short, limited and unclear.

Given a certain csv how can you upload it to a given Database?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have created a [Gist](https://gist.github.com/mmeendez8/276961449e6113e81ef6a54b4afe5d6c) with a Python class that contains all necessary methods to communicate with Teradata using pyodbc.

Specifically for uploading a csv file using this method your csv file must meet certain conditions:

1. Use pipes as delimiters: '|'
2. All values in csv must be double quoted: "value"
3. Avoid columns names in file

Example:

> "value1" | "value2" | "value3"
>
> "value1" | "value2" | "value3"
>
> "value1" | "value2" | "value3"

This can be achieved with pandas using:

```
import pandas as pd
from csv import QUOTE_ALL
data.to_csv('tmp.csv', index=False, sep='|', quotechar='"', quoting=QUOTE_ALL, header=False)
```

After this, you can use this function:

```
def upload_csv(database, csv_file, table, columns, user, password, verbose=True):
    """
    This function uses Fastlaod utily to upload csv file delimited with "|" instead of ',' and where all values in
    file are quoted. Ex: "value1" | "value2" | . . .
    :param csv_file: csv file without columns names
    :param table: Insertion table
    :param columns: Column names
    :param user: username
    :param password:
    :param verbose: True | False if output is required
    """

    script_text = fastload_template.substitute(DATA_FILE=csv_file,
                    COLUMN_DEFINITIONS=',\n'.join(['"' + column + '" (varchar(2000))' for column in columns]),
                    VALUES=',\n'.join([':' + '"' + column + '"' for column in columns]),
                    DATABASE=database, TABLE=table, USER=user, PASSWORD=password)

    tmp_file = csv_file[:-4]
    script = open(tmp_file, "w")
    script.writelines("%s\n" % script_text)
    script.close()

    try:
        if verbose:
            run(["fastload < " + tmp_file], check=True, shell=True)
        else:
            run(["fastload < " + tmp_file], check=True, shell=True, stdout=open(os.devnull, 'w'))

    except CalledProcessError as e:
        if e.args[0] != 8:  # Fastload gives error 8 but insert is working.. so don't touch :)
            raise e

    os.remove(tmp_file)
```

Comment: I've tried this numerous times and it always raises the error: Command '['fastload < tmp']' returned non-zero exit status 1.

Comment: Verbose was set to True. The error posted is the only thing returned.

Comment: Then try to inspect using fastload shell utility directly

Answer (score 0):

Just use `tdload` utility command that is provided by Teradata.

```
tdload -h teradata -u td_user -p td_pass \
-t TPT_Jobname1 \
-f filename.csv -d ',' --TargetWorkingDatabase target_db \
--TargetErrorLimit 100 target_db.staging_table1
```